# Replacing Fedora 20 with Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

Currently I'm using Fedora 20, but I need to replace it with Ubuntu 14.10. Can someone, please, provide step by step explanation for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the output from `mount` and `df` on your Fedora system and add them into your original question.

Comment: Why would you want to replace Fedora 20 with a version of Ubuntu that is [EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)?

Comment: Unless there is pressing need for this **14.10** version, I'd suggest installing 14.04 with the Long Term Support, if you don;t want to be installing the latest, cutting edge version.

Answer (score 2):

There is no conversion utility.

1. Backup the document files (including any code etc.) you have created, on to an external and/or cloud drive
2. Insert your Ubuntu installation media to the appropriate place on the server (optical drive/USB Port etc)
3. When asked if you want to keep the Fedora partition, decide if you want to keep it as a reference or wipe it out and answer accordingly. (I suggest keeping it against any "ooops" in the near future. You can remove it later)
4. Let the installer do its work.
5. Login to your system and restore your files from the beckup media